# How does this work in python : flat_array = sum( array_2d , [ ] )

Tags: python, arrays, list, multidimensional-array

To Convert a 2D array into 1D array in python , i found this method on leetcode. But can't find
How its working logically step by step ? Please explain.
Also someone said on leetcode that :
"This could be quadratic runtime complexity when array size gets really large"

Is this true? if yes, How?

```
a = [[4,2,5],[1,8,2],[7,5,6]]
flat  = sum(a,[])
flat
```

output : [4, 2, 5, 1, 8, 2, 7, 5, 6]

Comment: Flattening nested lists like that is a **very bad** idea, taking quadratic time. Don't do it.

Comment: @user2357112 , How shall i do this then ?

Comment: `[elem for sublist in a for elem in sublist]` would be one option.

Answer (score 2):

## How `sum` works?

In Python, lists can be concatenated with operator `+`:

```
>>> [1] + [2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
```

The `sum` function in Python is **similar** to:

```
>>> def my_sum(iterable, start=0):
...     for v in iterable:
...         start = start + v
...     return start
...
```

So for `sum(a, [])`, you can understand the following operations:

```
>>> [] + [4, 2, 5] + [1, 8, 2] + [7, 5, 6]
[4, 2, 5, 1, 8, 2, 7, 5, 6]
```

But this will not be a good practice, because each concatenation will produce a new list, rather than concatenation in place on one of the lists:

```
>>> a = [1]
>>> b = [2, 3]
>>> c = a + b
>>> a, b, c
([1], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3])
```

This means that each concatenation requires `O(n + m)` time (n and m are the lengths of the two lists respectively), rather than `O(m)`. For m lists with length n, the first time a list of length n will be concatenated with another list of length n, and the next time a list of length 2n will be concatenated with a list of length n... at the end, the total time spent will be:

```
(n + n) + (2n + n) + ... + (mn + n) = (m^2 + 3m) * n / 2 = O(m^2 * n)
```

## Better practice

The simple method is to use in place concatenate each time:

```
def concatenate(lists):
    result = []
    for lst in lists:
        result += lst
    return result
```

A more concise way is to use [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) and [`operator.iconcat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.iconcat):

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> from operator import iconcat
>>> reduce(iconcat, a, [])
[4, 2, 5, 1, 8, 2, 7, 5, 6]
```

You can also use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) to chain these lists, and then use the [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list) to construct:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(a))
[4, 2, 5, 1, 8, 2, 7, 5, 6]
```

Or use nested list [comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-python-grammar-comprehension):

```
>>> [val for lst in a for val in lst]
[4, 2, 5, 1, 8, 2, 7, 5, 6]
```

For performance comparison, please refer to: [How do I make a flat list out of a list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-do-i-make-a-flat-list-out-of-a-list-of-lists)

Answer (score -1):

Here `sum()` works as follows:
By default, `sum()` takes one required parameter which is a sequence of integers, as for the second optional parameter, it is defaulted to `0` to indicate that the sequence is of type `int`.
However, in the above case, it passes list of lists to `sum()` with the optional `start` parameter set to `[]` to indicate the sequence type is `list` which concatenates them.

However, there are better solutions to this problem. One of which is to use a for loop.

For further information, please check the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum).